# What are the benefits and disadvantages of having different JavaScript engines?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, browser, safari

Currently, there are different JavaScript engines maintained by Google, Mozilla, and Apple.
We have recently seen many browsers adopt V8, which is Chrome's JavaScript engine -- Brave, Opera, and Edge browsers.

My question is, why are there so many browser battles? Wouldn't it be better to have one universal JavaScript engine as opposed to different implementations?

That is, wouldn't it be better if Mozilla, Google, and Apple contributed to JavaScript language as a whole as opposed to maintaining their own implementations? What do you think the future looks like for JavaScript? What are the pros and cons of uniting JavaScript engines into one.

Comment: In any type of war, only the best contender comes out a winner. So, perhaps the best (and maybe only) advantage of the browser engine war is that it will result in very high quality js engines. Maybe another advantage of diversity is to have engines not just for different browsers but also for different hardware architectures (although the major engines are already ported to the major archs).

Comment: I think that big names like Apple, Google and Mozilla should contribute together **but only** to the language specs (ECMAScript) and let each of them have the freedom to build their own js engine implementations.